# Select anchor behind other anchor on SAME object?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have an object like this—

[image: part of a box]

and there a two anchors, one on top of the other like this–

[image: help]

I'm drawing it like this because I will be animating the path of the SVG I export from this drawing and I need it to draw in the correct way. I cannot join the anchors, make them separate objects, or any other method.

How do I select the anchor that is *behind* the front anchor when they are part of the *same* object?

**Note:** `cmd + click` does not work in this case ( *when they are a part of the same object* ).

Answer (score 2):

First go to `OBJECT > COMPOUND PATH > MAKE (Command 8)`

This shouldn't change your path, but it makes the next bit available...

Get the **Attributes** palette up (`WINDOW > ATTRIBUTES`) and make sure that you have selected `SHOW ALL` from the palette menu in the top right hand corner.

In the middle of the Attributes palette, you now have a couple of buttons that will reverse / un-reverse the path direction (this is only available for compound paths). Changing the direction of the path will change the order of the points and therefore which point is 'on top'. Just swap the direction back the other way when you need to grab the other point.