# Illustrator - Select an anchor point that is directly beneath another anchor point on the same path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, selections, anchor-point

Because these anchor points are on the same path, I cannot separate into different layers then lock one.

Even at full zoom, I cannot discern one point from the other and so only the "top" point gets selected.

I ended up having to mark the location of the point with intersecting guides, then dragging the upper point out of the way, then I could select and delete the point underneath, then drag the upper point back to the intersecting guides.

Although this solved my issue, it seems a bit klunky and I am hoping there is a better solution.

Obviously I can move and return the upper point successfully, whether by arrow key or by mapping the original point, but I am seeking a solution where I don't need to move the upper point at all.  Why I cannot move the upper point is neither negotiable nor a topic for debate.

Comment: Duplicate of http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/77972/select-anchor-behind-other-anchor-on-same-object

Comment: that works but you went a step too far.  it seems that making the compound path already reverses the direction and makes the anchor available.  I did search for my question before posting and that didn't pop up.  Perhaps it would be best to verify the path reversal upon making compound path and re-answering here so others searching with the terms i used can find the answer.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you, but making the compound path doesn't necessarily reverse the direction. Depends on what you started with.

Comment: I just tested it with a new drawing and it did reverse the direction again

Comment: It is odd that the last anchor point I created on my test path ends up being beneath the anchor point created first.  I would think it would be the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a self-cutting curve:

- take the direct selection tool
- deselect all
- check, which node gets selected by a click (try a move and undo it by Ctrl+Z)
- select both nodes by dragging over the area. Start from far enough and keep the selection narrow enough to avoid selecting more than the doublenode
- press shift and simultaneously click the doublenode, the other remains selected

You can move the not-easy-to-select-node by the arrow keys. Its handles obey the mouse.

Comment: Nice!  Exactly what I was looking for.  I definitely prefer this over making a compound path.

Comment: Nice tip! Thank you @user82991

Answer (score -1):

Do you need both?

1. Select top point with white arrow tool and delete it.
2. Select top point with white arrow tool, shift it 1 click left right up or down with the arrow keys, delete the bottom one and shift the top one back into position.
3. Ignore extra point and treat both as one

Comment: that is basically the same solution that I said I did in my question.  I know I can move the top point.  The idea is to get to the lower point without moving any anchor points.  I'm not even going to comment on your first and third solutions.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your problem. You asked for a less clunky solution and I gave one. Do you need both points? How did you get 2 points in same place on one path?

Comment: there are lots of ways to end up with 2 anchor points in the same place.  I need the top point but want to delete the bottom point without moving the top point.  Your #1 and #3 are completely useless and your #2 is exactly the same as the solution I already used.  There is nothing less klunky here.  You should just delete your answer.

Comment: Using the arrow keys, 2 taps, is less klunky and guaranteed precise rather than than your making intersecting guides, moving the point to it and back. I read your first comment about not finding use from my 1st and 3rd ideas, and your 2nd comment. Don't take it out on me, i'm trying to help.

Comment: are you serious?  Please delete your answer!

Comment: if you read the comments in my question, you would see that Chris already provided a much more correct answer in another post.

Comment: you got the answer you needed? then what are we doing here?